# Apply stream sum() method to N different fields of a List giving N sum results in a single iteration

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
class A
{
   Integer a;
   Integer b;
   Integer c;
}

List<A> inputList= func();
X x=new X();
int sumA = inputList.stream().mapToInt(e->e.getA()).sum();
int sumB = inputList.stream().mapToInt(e->e.getB()).sum();
int sumC = inputList.stream().mapToInt(e->e.getC()).sum();

x.setSumA(sumA);
x.setSumB(sumB);
x.setSumC(sumC);
```

This will solve it but there will be three iterations I want to perform it in single iteration without using for loop only using streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to compute the 3 sums in a single `Stream` pipeline:

```
X sums = inputList.stream()
                  .reduce(new X(0,0,0),
                          (x,e) -> new X(x.getSumA()+e.getA(),
                                         x.getSumB()+e.getB(),
                                         x.getSumC()+e.getC()),
                          (x1,x2) -> new X(x1.getSumA()+x2.getSumA(),
                                           x1.getSumB()+x2.getSumB(),
                                           x1.getSumC()+x2.getSumC()));
```

Comment: why new X every time in combiner and accumulator?

Comment: @VinayPrajapati, my guess: the solution assumes immutability of the instance variables

Comment: @VinayPrajapati well `reduce` does immutable reduction, so I went for the safe solution of creating a new instance in each operation. Perhaps this can be relaxed.

Comment: Well! I like simple and sleek solutions. `streams` seems to be complicated in such situations: 


```
        AtomicInteger sumA = new AtomicInteger();
        AtomicInteger sumB = new AtomicInteger();
        AtomicInteger sumC = new AtomicInteger();

        inputList.forEach(a -> {
            sumA.addAndGet(a.getA());
            sumB.addAndGet(a.getB());
            sumC.addAndGet(a.getC());
        });

     x.setSumA(sumA.get());
     x.setSumB(sumB.get());
     x.setSumC(sumC.get());
```

Comment: When `X` is mutable, a `collect` based solution would be more appropriate. But the definition of `X` has not been given in the question. In either case, it would improve the code if `X` has supportive methods for add resp. increment.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati your solution isn’t simple either, compared to a straight-forward loop.

Comment: Yeah @holger plain loops are way cleaner in such cases.